# Middleman Build assets without hash

Tags: middleman

How do I configure Middleman to build images without appending a hash to the filename? I'm referring to filepaths in javascript and need to know the full filename to refer to the files. My JS doesn't get updated with the hashed filenames like my CSS does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, figured it out. I had enabled `activate :asset_hash`. removing that from `config.rb` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to abandon `:asset_hash` just because you want to refer to them in JS. The asset hash extension actually attempts to rewrite paths in CSS and JavaScript automatically, but it sounds like whatever way you're linking them isn't getting detected.

You can always name your javascript something like `application.js.erb` and then have code like this:

```
var my_image = <%= image_path("myimage.png") %>;
```

That way you'll always have the right path.